# Node and NPM versions don't match

Tags: node.js, npm

The node and npm versions on my mac dont match. How do I downgrade npm to the same version as node?

Node:

```
$ node -v
$ v0.12.7
```

NPM:

```
$ npm -v
$ 2.14.4
```

Comment: they are separate projects and have their own separate versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm is a package manager for node.js. They don't have to be the same version. npm also gets updated more frequently than node, so they could not be expected to keep their versions the same

Comment: It would be good here to also talk to why `node` "pairs" *a specific* version of `npm` on the [Previous Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) page. For example, if I have `node` v7.7.2 and `npm` v4.1.2, then when using `brew` to downgrade/link to `node` v6.10, the `npm` version does not change. Is this problematic? If not, *why* bother "pairing" versions?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you can install any version of NPM. On debian distros, to use npm version 4.5.0 you need to do:

```
$ curl https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-4.5.0.tgz
$ tar -xvzf npm-4.5.0.tgz
$ cd package/
$ [sudo] make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Their versions are different because they are independent softwares. Their development is not synchronized.

I recommend updating NPM when you can; I'm running npm version 5.2.0

You can easily upgrade your NPM version using `npm install -g npm`